# Delphi image motion glitch

Tags: image, delphi

well, the problem might not be fixable but its really bothering me. I made a simple program that has three menus and used a timer to move the menu's left and right.

The problem comes when i move the images(menus) to the left of the screen(making the image.left negative. It makes this weird glitch, [white blocks that show up out of nowhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBQ4c.jpg). I'm not sure whats causing it, although the images(menus) are very high quality, if that's the cause....what can i do?

NB: amateur in Delphi

this is what i have

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, jpeg;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    pnl1: TPanel;
    tmr1: TTimer;
    btn1: TButton;
    pnl2: TPanel;
    pnl3: TPanel;
    btn2: TButton;
    btn3: TButton;
    tmr2: TTimer;
    tmr3: TTimer;
    img1: TImage;
    img2: TImage;
    img3: TImage;
    img4: TImage;
    pnlmain: TPanel;
    shp1: TShape;
    procedure btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure tmr1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure tmr2Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btn3Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure tmr3Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    iBar : Integer;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 tmr1.Enabled := True;
 btn1.Enabled := False;
 btn2.Enabled := true;
 btn3.Enabled := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.tmr1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if iBar = 1 then
  begin
  if pnl2.Left <> 70 then
  begin
  pnl1.Left := pnl1.Left-72;
  pnl2.Left := pnl2.Left-72;
  pnl3.Left := pnl3.Left-72;
  end
  else
  begin
     pnl1.Left := pnl1.Left-70;
     pnl2.Left := pnl2.Left-70;
     pnl3.Left := pnl3.Left-70;
     iBar := 2;
     tmr1.Enabled := False;
  end;
  end;

  if iBar = 3 then
  begin
     if pnl2.Left <> -70 then
     begin
     pnl3.Left := pnl3.Left+72;
     pnl2.Left := pnl2.Left+72;
     pnl1.Left := pnl1.Left+72;
     end
     else
     begin
     pnl3.Left := pnl3.Left+70;
     pnl2.Left := pnl2.Left+70;
     pnl1.Left := pnl1.Left+70;
     iBar := 2;
     tmr1.Enabled := False;
     end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 iBar := 1;
end;

procedure TForm1.btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  tmr2.Enabled := true;
  btn2.Enabled := False;
  btn1.Enabled := true;
  btn3.Enabled := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.tmr2Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if iBar = 3 then
  begin
  if pnl1.Left <> -140 then
  begin
     pnl3.Left := pnl3.Left+144;
     pnl1.Left := pnl1.Left+144;
     pnl2.Left := pnl2.Left+144;
  end
  else
  begin
     pnl3.Left := pnl3.Left+140;
     pnl1.Left := pnl1.Left+140;
     pnl2.Left := pnl2.Left+140;
     iBar := 1;
     tmr2.Enabled := False;
  end;
  end;

  if iBar = 2 then
  begin
     if pnl1.Left <> -70 then
     begin
     pnl2.Left := pnl2.Left+72;
     pnl1.Left := pnl1.Left+72;
     pnl3.Left := pnl3.Left+72;
     end
     else
     begin
     pnl2.Left := pnl2.Left+70;
     pnl1.Left := pnl1.Left+70;
     pnl3.Left := pnl3.Left+70;
     iBar := 1;
     tmr2.Enabled := False;
       end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.btn3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 tmr3.Enabled := True;
 btn3.Enabled := False;
 btn2.Enabled := true;
 btn1.Enabled := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.tmr3Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if iBar = 1 then
  begin
  if pnl3.Left <> 140 then
  begin
     pnl1.Left := pnl1.Left-144;
     pnl3.Left := pnl3.Left-144;
     pnl2.Left := pnl2.Left-144;
  end
  else
  begin
     pnl1.Left := pnl1.Left-140;
     pnl3.Left := pnl3.Left-140;
     pnl2.Left := pnl2.Left-140;
     iBar := 3;
     tmr3.Enabled := False;
       end;
  end;

  if iBar = 2 then
  begin
     if pnl3.Left <> 70 then
     begin
     pnl2.Left := pnl2.Left-72;
     pnl3.Left := pnl3.Left-72;
     pnl1.Left := pnl1.Left-72;
     end
     else
     begin
     pnl2.Left := pnl2.Left-70;
     pnl3.Left := pnl3.Left-70;
     pnl1.Left := pnl1.Left-70;
     iBar := 3;
     tmr3.Enabled := False;
       end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: You are not supposed to move controls for image movement animation. You are supposed to paint on a canvas. Have a timer that will update internally stored coordinates (for each graphics object) and will be calling `Invalidate` for the control containing that canvas (e.g. `TPaintBox`). The rest is painting graphics on that canvas by those coordinates.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've looked into the TPaintBox, which is a very interesting concept, unfortunately, what I see has some limitations, compared to what I really want to create. What I'm trying to achieve here is to create a stylish UI, that has a panning transition effect, as in, when you select a menu tab, it slides horizontally to that menu section. My UI is mostly images with buttons in the foreground invisible. I might be underestimating the capabilities of the TPaintBox, and if I am, could you please explain further about the implementation of this

Answer (score 1):

You will never achieve smooth animation of any sort when driving the animation from a timer and/or relying on windows controls as your "sprites".

The standard timer component in Delphi uses Windows message based timer events, which means that the processing of these events relies on the message handling of your UI thread, which is also dealing with mouse movements, painting and a whole host of other messages required to keep your UI responsive.

Timer messages take the absolute lowest priority.

Similarly, windows controls are designed to manage interaction with a user.  Animation and effects can be used as part of that interaction, but the system is not optimised for physically moving controls around the screen since this is an extremely unusual behaviour for a UI control.

You might remember some of the older Windows "joke" programs with a message box where the "OK" button jumps around the screen whenever you try to click on it ... ?  Controls that move around are more often annoying than useful.

Animating in this way can be OK as a proof of concept or prototype to put in front of a user to elicit feedback, but you will always run into "glitches" of the sort you describe.

For your "production" code you should re-think your UI implementation.

If you really need an animated menu then design and implement a control that implements that as a behaviour within a single control.

Manage the animation of the elements in that control (i.e. updating the "model" of the positions of the elements) on a background thread.  To render each "frame", incorporate a separate thread specifically to post messages to the control to paint itself as frequently as required to achieve smooth animation, this painting is then the only code that has to operate in concert with all the other UI messages your app is dealing with.

As an efficiency refinement, if you have a number of controls being animated in this way in your form/app, you can usually come up with a scheme that uses a single thread to post the paint messages to all the required controls.